# Converting NAs to dummies for specific columns

Tags: r

I am trying to make dummies out of some specific tables. I know how to do it for one column, but I need to do it for 23 at the same time.

My problem is not converting the NAs, but selecting specific columns to convert.

I tried the following and it converted the whole table into zeros and ones:

```
table <- ifelse(is.na(table),0,1)
```

I also tried this

```
table<- ifelse(is.na(table[,3:25]),0,1)
```

and this was not good at all

Comment: My problem is not converting the NAs, but selecting specific columns.

Comment: @Ivancito - you already know how to select specific columns `table[,3:25]`. Do you want to overwrite only certain columns like `table[,3:25] <- ifelse(is.na(table[,3:25]),0,1)` ?

Comment: It worked. I tried this before and it didnt work: table[,3:25] <- ifelse(is.na(table),0,1)

Now that this is solved im having trouble to sum this dummies into a new variable like this:
table <- table%>%mutate(profundidad = sum(table[,3:17])

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A Tidyverse approach would be to use mutate_at to specify the columns you want to apply the function to.  Here I am replacing all NA's with 0 and all non NA's with 1.

```
table <- table %>% 
mutate_at(c(3:25), ~replace(., is.na(.), 0))%>% 
mutate_at(c(3:25), ~replace(., !is.na(.), 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

A data.table solution.

**Data**

```
dt = data.table(
  x = c(1, NA, 3),
  y = c(NA, NA, 3),
  z = c(1, 2, 3),
  w = c(NA, 2, NA)
)

> dt
    x  y z  w
1:  1 NA 1 NA
2: NA NA 2  2
3:  3  3 3 NA
```

**Code**

We can either convert NA to a dummy across the whole data.table..

```
> dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 1, 0))]
   x y z w
1: 0 1 0 1
2: 1 1 0 0
3: 0 0 0 1
```

Or select a column interval (cols) on which we want to generate the dummies using the .SDcols argument:

```
cols = 2:4
dt[, (cols) :=lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 1, 0)), .SDcols = cols]

> dt
    x y z w
1:  1 1 0 1
2: NA 1 0 0
3:  3 0 0 1
```